# Java : checking the value in Java from a JSON Format

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON as shown below

```
{
    "qty": "1",
    "dswer": 0,
    "bag": {
        "dm": "2",
        "rate": "---",
        "ghy": "3013-04-05T00:00:00.000-05:00",
        "dee": "301304",
        "desc": "SSAA APR 05 2013 --- BGG"
    }
}
```

My requirement is that if the rate attribute in above Json is --- then treat it that as as InValid Request .

I dont want to assign this JSON to a Java class , for various reasons

So i was trying this way

```
package com;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {


        String str = "{\r\n" + 
                "    \"qty\": \"1\",\r\n" + 
                "    \"dswer\": 0,\r\n" + 
                "    \"bag\": {\r\n" + 
                "        \"dm\": \"2\",\r\n" + 
                "        \"rate\": \"---\",\r\n" + 
                "        \"ghy\": \"3013-04-05T00:00:00.000-05:00\",\r\n" + 
                "        \"dee\": \"301304\",\r\n" + 
                "        \"desc\": \"SSAA APR 05 2013 --- CALL\"\r\n" + 
                "    }\r\n" + 
                "}";

        if(str.contains("rate:---"))
        {
            System.out.println("InValid");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Valid");
        }


    }

}
```

But its always displaying as Valid .

Please tell me how to solve this ??

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(str.contains("rate:---")) // is false because
if(str.contains("\"rate\": \"---\"")) // would be true
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `if` condition needs to be this:-

```
if(str.contains("\"rate\": \"---\""))
```

Since in your JSON, both `rate` & `---` are enclosed within double-quotes, you need to add those in your `if` condition by escaping those.

Even though this would work, I strongly recommend you parse your JSON properly using either `org.json.JSONObject` or `com.google.gson.JsonObject`.